# Search by name and number both within in single search bar

Tags: java, javascript, jquery

I want to implement a functionality in java where I can search by both by username or by employee number within a single search bar.

I am looking for a simple solution either at client side or at java side

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean Java or JavaScript?

Comment: What is your specific question?

Comment: @JJ.: I guess both: *"I am looking for a simple solution either at client side or at java side"*

Comment: What are we querying?.. A database? A Java Collection? A JavaScript Object? Please give more info.

Comment: we are querying the database

Answer (score 1):

Just perform the first search, if it gives a result use it. If not then do the second search.

If usernames must contain alphabetic characters and employee numbers cannot contain them then you could look at the contents of the string and decide which search to run based on that.